# Unix: file names and location to excel sheet

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am new to Unix system. I am not sure is this task possible or how ?

I have this directory structure

```
c: parent dir/ child dir/file1
c: parent dir/ child dir/file2
c: parent dir/ child dir/file3
.
.
```

I need to export all this files name and its full location(path) to an excel sheet.

Any hint/help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Why not export to a `csv` file?

Comment: You list what appear to be drive letters on your paths, which Unix doesn't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the list returned from `find` to a CSV file.  To get a list of files only (not directories) in a specific folder, not recursively, you would do:

```
find `pwd` -maxdepth 1 -type f -print > files.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to write to an excel sheet, as it is not a text file. The best approach would probably be to output your data to a file in a format such as CSV or just plain text and then copy and paste that into an excel sheet.

Example:

```
$] find `pwd` > myfile.txt
/absolute/path/to/file0
/absolute/path/to/file1
...
```

And copy and paste that to your excel sheet. Or you could parse the data in from `find` and insert a comma after each line. I'll leave that as homework for you... should be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a Unix system right now, but from a console window try

```
cd "root of directory structure"
find . -print > myFiles.csv
```

Load the .csv into Excel then putter as needed.

You may want to read up on the `find` command - it's very useful.